# Find the largest n such that n! < k in Haskell, using foldl and an infinite series

Tags: haskell

This seems very simple to state in the title, but I'm having difficulty coding it up.  I'm looking for the largest n such that n! < a given k.

Here's what I've tried:

```
func1 = foldl (*) 1 [1..] . takeWhile (\x -> x < (read "1e100" :: Scientific ))

func2 = (\x -> foldl (*) 1 [1..x] . takeWhile (x < (read "1e100" :: Scientific )))

func3 = do
        forM_ [1..] $ \x -> do
            let y = foldl (*) 1 [1..x]
            when y >= (read "1e100" :: Scientific ) $
                putStrLn x
                return ()

func4 k = let nfac = foldl (*) 1 [1..n]
              where nfac > k
-- func4 (read "1e100" :: Scientific )
```

I'm using the Data.Scientific library as k will usually be large.

What's an idiomatic way to phrase this correctly?

Comment: Using `filter` and `last`.

Comment: As for `func3`, this will not work, since `return` does *not* terminate the control flow.

Comment: You can't write `list . takeWhile condition`, since lists are not functions and can not be composed. Use instead basic application `takeWhile condition list`. Also, you can't `foldl` on an infinite list -- that will diverge. You probably want `scanl` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: divide your program in functions that each perform a dedicated task.

We can first define a function to calculate the factorial:

```
fact :: (Num a, Enum a) => a -> a
fact x = foldl (*) 1 [1..x]
```

Now we can generate a list of 2-tuples where the first item is the `i`, and the second the `i!`:

```
facts :: (Num a, Enum a) => [(a, a)]
facts = map (\i -> (i, fact i)) [1..]
```

Now we can use a `takeWhile` to filter this list to only return the tuples for which the second item (the `i!` thus), is smaller than `n`:

```
factsless :: (Num a, Enum a) => a -> [(a, a)]
factsless n = takeWhile (\(_, fi) -> fi < n) facts
```

Now we can use the `last` to obtain the *last* tuple of this list, and then use `fst` to obtain the corresponding `i`:

```
solution :: (Num a, Enum a) => a -> a
solution n = fst (last (factsless n))
```

Given `n` is large, only an `Integer` can represent that number. So it is probably safer to use an `Integer` for `a`, since otherwise it is possible the less than check will never fail, hence overflow will occur.

For example:

```
Prelude> solution 2
1
Prelude> solution 3
2
Prelude> solution 4
2
Prelude> solution 5
2
Prelude> solution 6
2
Prelude> solution 7
3
Prelude> solution 10
3
Prelude> solution 100
4
Prelude> solution 10000
7 
Prelude> solution (10^100)
69
```

Since factorials are *integrals*, it is better to avoid floating point numbers, normally integers will be more precide, compact and efficient.

**Optimizations**:

we can boost performance of a calculating the factorials, by generating an infinite list, for example with `scanl`:

```
facts :: (Num a, Enum a, Num b, Enum b) => [(a, b)]
facts = zip [1..] (scanl (*) 1 [2..])
```

Other optimizations are possible, but I leave this as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the fold with a scan, and put *its* result through `takeWhile ...`. And then index it and take a `last`!

But first untangle the `read`, to turn it into a plain argument value. It doesn't matter where it comes from, for the algorithm that you're implementing. Thus

```
factProblem :: Integer -> Int
factProblem k = -- fst . last . zip [0..] 
                pred . length
                   . takeWhile (< k) . scanl (*) 1 $ [1..]

main :: IO ()
main = getLine >>= print . factProblem . read
```

Comment: Isn't `fst . last . zip [0..]` equivalent to `pred . length` ? (at least when defined)

Comment: @chi nice observation. of course the `fst` snippet follows the specs *self-evidently*; `length` not quite. I guess what's warranted in such cases is to use the second, while leaving the first as a comment. thanks!

Comment: @Will Ness Does this type check..? I had to change the signature to `factProblem :: Integer -> Int` on ghci.